# TypeError at /admin 'set' object is not reversible. Ошибка джанго

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

При попытке зайти в админ панель 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/. Появляется ошибка 'set' object is not reversible. urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('news/',include('news.urls')),
    path('', include('mainApp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('lab1/', include('helloworld.urls')),

]
```

ещё один urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from news.models import Article
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Article.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],template_name="news/posts.html")),
    path('', include('mainApp.urls')),

]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['news',
 'mainApp',
 'helloworld',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 249, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 221, in inner
    if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 55, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 520, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 471, in _populate
    url_pattern._populate()
  File "C:\Users\dakak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 454, in _populate
    for url_pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'set' object is not reversible
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns= {
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
}
```

Comment: Покажите весь трейсбек.

Comment: И все `urls.py`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 , Добавил.

Comment: это не все урлы

Comment: Ой, не заметил. Добавил последний

Comment: В нём вместо квадратных скобок фигурные, то есть это не список паттернов, как должно быть, а множество.